# What client-side web languages can support multiple threads?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write an application that is web-based and I was originally using javascript. However I need to be able to use multiple threads. What other web languages support multiple threads?

Edit: I am looking for client-side.

Comment: Do you mean client-side or server-side?

Comment: You need to expand your question, its very vague

Comment: Looking for Client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-threaded Javascript is something that has been proposed but is not currently possible (apart from web workers, which is another story). Javascript is an asynchronous language anyway, which is why threading was not originally part of Javascript. No other client-side language support multi-threaded operations.

Answer (score 5):

If you need concurrency in client-side JavaScript have a look at WebWorkers:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Workers

To find out which version of browser support Webworkers, see [this table](http://caniuse.com/webworkers).